# Onclick Button Function to Expand Text Box

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I was following along with a tutorial to create an expanding and closing text box but I can't seem to get the onclick function to work, when I click the button it doesn't expand the text box. Do you see any errors that would prevent the onclick function from working? Thank you!

```js
var content = document.getElementbyId("content");
var button = document.getElementById("show-more");

button.onclick = function() {
  if (content.className == "open") {
    //shrink the box
    content.className = "";
    button.innerHTML = "Show More";
  } else {
    //expand the box
    content.className = "open";
    button.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc.</p>
</div>

<a id="show-more">Show More</a>
```

Comment: Your browser's development console is telling you that the code is failing on the very first line of JavaScript because `getElementbyId` is not a function.  Always check the browser console for errors.

Comment: As a side note, do not use an anchor (`<a>`) if you want to fire a trick. Use a button (prefereably with an onclick trigger) instead. Anchors is for directing to a HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the typo `document.getElementbyId` to `document.getElementById`and it should work.

look for the '**B**' in the first line.

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var button = document.getElementById("show-more");

button.onclick = function() {
  if (content.className == "open") {
    //shrink the box
    content.className = "";
    button.innerHTML = "Show More";
  } else {
    //expand the box
    content.className = "open";
    button.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc.</p>
</div>

<a id="show-more">Show More</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies! I capitalized the "B", then at least received another null error. Problem was solved when I wrapped the onclick function in:
```
window.onload = function(){ 
    // your code 
};
```